# this.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None is giving compile time error on ios6

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using below code for adjusting frame for ios7

```
if(!AppDelegate.IsIOS6orBelow)
    this.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
```

but it is giving compile time error in ios6,I know it is new property in ios7 but what's the solution for ios6?(Other developer is working on old version of xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your code to reference iOS7 API but that still compiles on to of iOS6 `monotouch.dll`, you have to wrap that code in preprocessor directives.

```cs
#if IOS7
    this.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
#endif
```

and you have to define IOS7 in your project properties.

If you don't do that, it will fail at compile time.

Comment: Can u explain where should I define this preprocessor directive?

Comment: Project > [project] options > Compiler > Define Symbols. separate them with semicolons (`;`)

Comment: note: they aren't really preprocessor directives, as they're is no proprocessor in the c# compilation chain, but meh, it works as if.

Comment: I had added this preprocessor directive,but it is not working on device,It is giving wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler is not aware of which version of iOS you're targeting. IOW if you get a compile time **error** then either:

- something is wrong in your source;
- you're referencing a version of `monotouch.dll` that does not have the feature you want (e.g. before Xamarin.iOS 7.0 you won't get the new iOS7 API);

note: You might want to add more source and the exact error in your question.